# $this->escape() on Models

Tags: zend-framework, escaping, models

Is there a way that I can use `$this->escape()` on models or inside the controller?

Comment: $this->escape is specific to a view. If you need to call it from your controller or your model, there is something wrong in your architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$this->escape()` is used in view, its similar to `htmlentities()` , `htmlspecialchars`

If you are looking for Quoting Values and Identifiers you should use `quote()` , `quoteInto()` methods.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.quoting.quote-into

Comment: Yes, the only thing I was unsure is why he needs escape in controller, or model ie why I kept link to Zend DB ;)

Answer (score 3):

`$this->escape()` is an alias to [htmlspecialchars()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and [htmlentities()](http://cn.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php). Therefore, you can simply use them as if or write your own method.

You should avoid to use `escape()` in your models but instead use them in your controllers (or even better, in your view) as follow:

```
// instantiate Zend_View
$view = new Zend_View();
$view->setEscape('htmlentities');
$obj = new My_Model();
$view->setEscape(array($obj, 'methodName'));
echo $view->render(...);
```

Comment: Or just `$this->view->escape('foo');` in controllers

Comment: Or just hold off escaping altogether until you get into the view-scripts themselves.